# python locale set currency at end of string

Tags: python, position, locale, currency

I got my currency fixed in maybe not the best lookign way but it works, what I need now is that the currency symbol will be placed at the end of the string.
When i try p_sign_posn = 3 at different functions of locale, i cant get it to work.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
bruto = locale.currency(total, grouping=True).replace('$', 'ISK ')
tax = locale.currency(tax, grouping=True).replace('$', 'ISK ')
netto = locale.currency(netto, grouping=True).replace('$', 'ISK ')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to set values (in your case LC_MONETARY.p_sign_posn) into locale but you always can write a little function:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

def addAndReverseSign(number, grouping=True):
    sign, number = locale.currency(number, grouping).replace('$', 'ISK ').split(' ')
    print number, sign

addAndReverseSign(123)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to set-up your own locale in Python. One way to achieve the results you want would be like this:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'icelandic')

total, tax, netto = 100.00, 8.32, 108.32

bruto = locale.currency(total, grouping=True).replace('kr.', 'ISK ')
tax = locale.currency(tax, grouping=True).replace('kr.', 'ISK ')
netto = locale.currency(netto, grouping=True).replace('kr.', 'ISK ')

print bruto  # 100,00 ISK
print tax    # 8,32 ISK
print netto  # 108,32 ISK
```

A more involved, but more general, approach would be to use this modified version of the [*recipe given in the documentation for formatting currency*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#recipes) to which I've added support for four additional keyword arguments corresponding to their names in the`locale`module.

```
from decimal import Decimal

def moneyfmt(value, places=2, curr='', sep=',', dp='.',
             pos='', neg='-', trailneg='',
             p_cs_precedes=True, n_cs_precedes=True,
             p_sep_by_space=False, n_sep_by_space=False):
    """Convert numeric value to a money formatted string.

    places:   required number of places after the decimal point
    curr:     optional currency symbol before the sign (may be blank)
    sep:      optional grouping separator (comma, period, space, or blank)
    dp:       decimal point indicator (comma or period)
              only specify as blank when places is zero
    pos:      optional sign for positive numbers: '+', space or blank
    neg:      optional sign for negative numbers: '-', '(', space or blank
    trailneg: optional trailing minus indicator:  '-', ')', space or blank
    p_cs_precedes: currency symbol precedes positive value*
    n_cs_precedes: currency symbol precedes negative value*
    p_sep_by_space: currency symbol separated by space from the positive value*
    n_sep_by_space: currency symbol separated by space from the negative value*
      (keywords added*)

    >>> d = Decimal('-1234567.8901')
    >>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$')
    '-$1,234,567.89'
    >>> moneyfmt(d, places=0, sep='.', dp='', neg='', trailneg='-')
    '1.234.568-'
    >>> moneyfmt(d, curr='$', neg='(', trailneg=')')
    '($1,234,567.89)'
    >>> moneyfmt(Decimal(123456789), sep=' ')
    '123 456 789.00'
    >>> moneyfmt(Decimal('-0.02'), neg='<', trailneg='>')
    '<0.02>'

    """
    if not isinstance(value, Decimal):
        value = Decimal(value)
    q = Decimal(10) ** -places      # 2 places --> '0.01'
    sign, digits, exp = value.quantize(q).as_tuple()
    result = []
    digits = map(str, digits)
    build, next = result.append, digits.pop
    if p_cs_precedes:
       build(curr)
       if p_sep_by_space:
            build(' ')
    if sign:
        build(trailneg)
    for i in range(places):
        build(next() if digits else '0')
    build(dp)
    if not digits:
        build('0')
    i = 0
    while digits:
        build(next())
        i += 1
        if i == 3 and digits:
            i = 0
            build(sep)
    build(neg if sign else pos)
    if not p_cs_precedes:
        if p_sep_by_space:
            build(' ')
        build(curr)
    return ''.join(reversed(result))

# try all the combinations of new options on a positive and negative number
from itertools import izip, product

kwrds = 'p_cs_precedes', 'n_cs_precedes', 'p_sep_by_space', 'n_sep_by_space'
for netto in [100, -100]:
    for combo in product((False,True), (False,True), (False,True), (False,True)):
        kwargs = dict(izip(kwrds, combo))
        print '{!r}'.format(moneyfmt(netto, curr='ISK', **kwargs))
    print
```